# Pass child state value to Parent state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-select

I am trying to use the react-select component at this page in Github, everything is ok, created a multiselect component as the one of the example below and it seems to work correctly. My question is, how do i pass this controls selected value, that is a array, at that same components state, to a Parent state value component in which i use this control? Have looked for a "React way" solution for days with no luck.

[react-select Multiselect control](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/Multiselect.js)

Here is my Parent component i which i use the control.

```
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
import Multiselect from './Multiselect';
import React from 'react';

export default class Formcontacto extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectchildValue: [],      
    }

    this.handlechildvalueSelect = this.handlechildvalueSelect.bind(this);       

    }

    handlechildvalueSelect(e) {
        this.setState({ selectchildValue: e.target.value });
    }

    render() {
            return (
            <div className='cSelectclass'>
              <form method="post" action="/send" className="cForm" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
             <label>
                    Name:
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
              </label>
            <Multiselect value={this.handlechildvalueSelect} className='cSelects'/>
            <input
              type="submit"
              className="cSubmit"
              formvalues={this.state}
              email="myemail@gmail.com"
              onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}
              value="Submit"/>
            <button
              className="cButton"
              onClick={this.handleClearForm}>Errase form...</button>
            </form>
              </div>
            );
      }
}
```

Comment: You can do that using `props`, like `this.props.parentFunction(e.target.value)`...in your `handlechildvalueSelect` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Multiselect` from the example, then you should rewrite it a bit to accept some `onChangeSelect` function

```
propTypes: {
    label: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
    onSelectChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
},
getDefaultProps: function() {
  return {
    value: [],
  };
},
getInitialState () {
    return {
        removeSelected: true,
        disabled: false,
        crazy: false,
        stayOpen: false,
        value: [], <-- remove this, cause it will be passed by parent component in props
        rtl: false,
    };
},
handleSelectChange (value) {
    console.log('You\'ve selected:', value);
    this.props.onSelectChange(value);
},
...
render () {
   const { value } = this.props;
}
```

Then in your parent component

```
handlechildvalueSelect(value) {
    this.setState({ selectchildValue: value });
}

render() {
  <Multiselect
    onSelectChange={this.handlechildvalueSelect}
    value={this.state.selectchildValue}
    className='cSelects'
  />
}
```

Comment: Yes, i think props is the correct way to go thank you, i need to implement this but this is the correct answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a method in your parent component that accepts the selected values and then call that as a prop in the child:

Parent:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Formcontacto extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
      this.state = {
        selectedValues: []      
      }
    }

    updateState(values) {
        this.setState({ selectedValues: values });
    }

    render() {
            return <Formcontacto updateState={this.updateState} />;
      }
}


import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
import Multiselect from './Multiselect';
import React from 'react';

export default class Formcontacto extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectchildValue: [],      
    }

    this.handlechildvalueSelect = this.handlechildvalueSelect.bind(this);       

    }

    handlechildvalueSelect(e) {
        this.setState({ selectchildValue: e.target.value });
        this.props.updateState(e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
            return (
            <div className='cSelectclass'>
              <form method="post" action="/send" className="cForm" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
             <label>
                    Name:
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
              </label>
            <Multiselect value={this.handlechildvalueSelect} className='cSelects'/>
            <input
              type="submit"
              className="cSubmit"
              formvalues={this.state}
              email="myemail@gmail.com"
              onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}
              value="Submit"/>
            <button
              className="cButton"
              onClick={this.handleClearForm}>Errase form...</button>
            </form>
              </div>
            );
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice but it is basicaly what i have done